# Could not autowire method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire method:
```

This is my spring's xml configuration.

```
<bean ...>   
...
    <property name="InfoModel" ref="InfoModel"></property>
</bean>
```

Here is my code where I am autowiring this in Java class

```
  private InfoModel infoModel;

  @Autowired
  public void setInfoModel(InfoModel infoModel) {
    this.infoModel= infoModel;
  }
```

Am I missing something. I suspect that I should make an `Interface` of **InfoModel** in order to make it autowire?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.model.InfoModel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
```

Comment: Can you post the InfoModel class? I assume it is a concrete class.

Comment: could you please post a little more info about your exception stack trace

Comment: InfoModel  class only initialze some values in it.

Comment: usually all the information required is contained in the exception stack trace. P.S. are there any exceptions regarding InfoModel bean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you do `@Autowired` you don't need to mark it as property in xml. just declare InfoModel as bean in XML and remove `property` from xml for you bean where you have injected `InfoModel`

Summing up

**1** You need a bean definition in your XML for `InfoModel`

**2** You need to remove `property` from XML

**3** Make sure you have made your context annotation driven by adding

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: If he's using annotations, he could just put `@Component` in type level of `InfoModel` instead of putting in the XML. Although it is very similar.

Answer (score 1):

If the stack trace says there are no matching beans of said type, then that's what wrong.

Add the InfoModel bean to the spring application context, e.g. by declaring the bean in the same xml configuration:

```
<bean id="InfoModel" class="com.model.InfoModel" />
```

btw. you shouldn't capitalize the first letter of the bean identifier, follow the same naming convention as for variables, ie. lowerCamelCase.
Autowiring and explicitly injecting the dependency is also redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write @Autowired before the private Info.... Declaration. and remove entry from the xml as mentioned by jigar.

Comment: Putting the `@Autowired` annotation in a field or in a method accessor is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly annotate your `InfoModel` class with a Type Level Annotation such `@Component`, `@Service`, or `@Repository`. All of them are very similar. If your `InfoModel` is not properly annotated you will receive this famous "No matching bean..." error. Try annotating your `InfoModel` class with `@Component` to look like this:

```
@Component
public class InfoModel {
  // code
}
```