# Spring Security cannot reach custom userDetailsService Bean in Service layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Edit: I just realized that the issue does not come from spring-security not being able to instantiate userDetailsServiceImpl that is referenced in the spring-security.xml file, it is the addUserFormController that cannot be instantiated because it cannot autowire the UserDetailsServiceImpl. So the problem comes from the fact that this Controller cannot reach, for whatever reasons, this Service bean UserDetailsServiceImpl. I think I did properly made my component scan, by only scanning the controllers in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, and all the other one except controller in the applicationContext.**

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate and I am trying to integrate Spring Security with a custom UserDetailsService and an Assembler.

It looks like my spring security cannot access the beans that are supposed to be scanned by the applicationContext.xml.

When loading my application I am running into the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addUserFormController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.controller.AddUserFormController.setUserDetailsService(com.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
```

Here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_Admin')" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/listing.htm" />

        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login_error.htm" default-target-url="/listing.htm"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="com.daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="com.daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- This listener creates the root application Context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<!-- Load everything except @Controllers -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.service</value>
            <value>com.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutospringsource" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" />
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

And finally, my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

    <!-- Load @Controllers only -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

My AddUserFormController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register.htm")

public class AddUserFormController {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
```

My UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
package com.service;
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;
```

Comment: It seems that you declared it as in package com.service but in the definition the package is missing.

Comment: @Jinzhao Wu - The package is not missing, I just did not paste it in my post. I edited my initial post to reflect that.

Comment: Are you sure that `userDetailsService` is instantitated from the spring container?If your see your exception It's not able to find the instance of `userDetailsService`. So, see in the console when the server started you can see what all the beans are created.

Comment: @Jinzhao Wu - Yes, the package declaration is there in AddUserFormController: package com.controller;

Comment: Is it the case? [Could not autowire method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635861/could-not-autowire-method)

Comment: @Srinivas - INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@52b79d68: defining beans ....,userEntityDao,assembler,securityRoleEntityServiceImpl,userDetailsService and so on... they are all here.

Comment: @Jinzhao Wu - I checked the link you gave me and tried to add @ Component to the UserDetailsServiceImpl class but it did not made any change. Plus, I cannot remove the property referencing my userDetailsServiceImpl bean in the spring-security.xml context, as it is referenced in the authentication-manager declaration, as well as in the bean Dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: Edit:I just realized that the issue does not come from spring-security not being able to instantiate userDetailsServiceImpl that is referenced in the spring-security.xml file, it is the addUserFormController that cannot be instantiated because it cannot autowire the UserDetailsServiceImpl.So the problem comes from the fact that this Controller cannot reach, for whatever reasons, this Service bean UserDetailsServiceImpl.I think I did properly made my component scan, by only scanning the controllers in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, and all the other one except controller in the applicationContext.

Comment: One question to help me understand your code. Do you need the authenticationManager, com.DaoAuthenticationProvider beans in the spring security xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix that issue.

In my AddUserFormController, I had this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register.htm")

public class AddUserFormController {

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
```

Here is how it looks now:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register.htm")
public class AddUserFormController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
```

I moved the @Autowired from the setter directly to the attribute, AND most important, I changed the type of userDetailsService to UserDetailsService, rather than UserDetailsServiceImpl.